# codeigniter smarty blank page issue

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

Is there a way to force codeigniter to display smarty errors?

I'm trying to include a file:

```
{include file="header.tpl.php"}
```

but in result I have a blank page with no error.

I have errors set to E_ALL and php errors are being displayed.

thanks.

Comment: Is [Smarty error reporting](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.error.reporting.tpl) enabled? Also maybe of interest:  [http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11351](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11351)

Comment: yes I do $config['error_reporting'] = "E_ALL";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smarty changes the error reporting level when it is invoked, and changes it back before it returns. How you change the setting will depend on how you are using Smarty and integrating it with Codeigniter - for me I can change it in config/smarty.php, but the core Smarty way is like this:

```
$smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
```

If you have extended the Smarty class to make your own, you'll probably want something like

```
$this->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
```

In your constructor instead.

If you do that, errors should start showing!

Comment: Great! it worked when changed in Smarty.php, strange that this didn't worked: $this->error_reporting   = $this->CI->config->item('error_reporting'); and in config was $config['error_reporting'] = "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE";

Comment: This is in my config: $config['error_reporting']      = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE; Note that there should NOT be quotes around the E_ALL bit, E_ALL and E_NOTICE are constants.